# Get list of all pods (including deleted) for kubernetes cluster? (AWS EKS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I need to do an audit of our AWS-managed kubernetes cluster (EKS). Specifically, I want to generate a list of all pods that were in a state of Running at some point.

Is there any functionality in kubectl that will get this information for me?

The cluster has been running for about 10 weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a complete history in AWS CloudWatch logs. You simply need to enable "Audit" logging in the "Logging" section of the EKS console.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/control-plane-logs.html for more info

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get it from the pod itself, but you can do:

```
kubectl get events | grep Started
```

Comment: Events seem to be cleared out periodically so this solution won't work for my problem (I need to get a list of all pods that ever started since the cluster was created)

Comment: @JamesWierzba hmmm. Not sure where this can be found if not in the events.

Answer (score 0):

Please execute:

```
$ kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep Running
```

This command will show you not only all pods in Running state but also namespaces where this pod have been deployed.

More information you can find here: [kubectl-cheatsheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/).

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: This will only show currently Running pods. I need a comprehensive list of all pods that were ever Running (even if they were deleted weeks ago) since the cluster was created.